# Dismiss uialertview programmatically in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uialertview

I have implemented `UIAlertview` category in custom class. i am calling that method from my `uitableviewcontroller` to show an alert .But in iOS7 on iPhone 4 device, that alertview is coming multiple times while fast clicking on the uitableviewcells.

I am trying to dismiss the alertview if it is already opened by using the following code.

```
for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
    for (NSObject* o in w.subviews)
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
            [(UIAlertView*)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
```

But this code is not working in iOS 7. I am not sure the way which i follow is correct or not.

Comment: You could give the view a tag or assign it to a property because it seems like you want to keep around just one instance of it anyway.

Comment: I use to have an array containing displayed alert, and iterate through the array to dismiss them in viewWillDisappear

Comment: You almost never want to iterate through subviews and mess with stuff that way, you run into all sorts of bad problems.

Comment: While a solution to this could simply be hold onto references of the alertViews and dismiss them all when you want, I might recommend perhaps rethinking exactly why you want to show all these alerts and dismiss them programmatically in the first place.. Seems to me to be a pretty bad user experience.

Comment: @Mike while fast clicking on uitableviewcells, those are returning multiple alerts. so i am checking whether the alert is opened or not?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you display the alerts?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the through  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` is a bad idea. Better concept is to hold the reference of an active `UIAlertView` and dismiss it when you want.

**Note:**
Make use of the `UIAlertView` property  `isVisible`, which indicates whether the AlertView is displayed.

**Example:**

```
if (YES == alertViewInstance.isVisible)
{
   //dismiss your alert view
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i tried isVisible property also but no use. it is not working in iOS7.